# I am getting the error in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am getting this error is django rest framework

```
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-gradient-able/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 25, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' (/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-gradient-able/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py)
```

Comment: python_2_unicode_compatible feature has only been added in Django 1.5 version.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible

Comment: or you can use this `from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible` instead of `from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible`